# I installed guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.0 and now laravel passport is not working

Tags: php, laravel

I installed guzzlehttp/guzzle with composer, composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle ~6.0, after that, all the application is running ok, but laravel passport is not working, it said the next error

> ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'Parser' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in file back/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Configuration.php on line 22,

Any suggestion? thank you

Comment: then update passport version as well

Answer (score 0):

try this i am not sure
remove version when you install guzzle like this.

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

and do

```
composer install and composer update
```

may be it will solve your problem

Comment: I did it, with any result :(

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan jwt:secret
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Before run this commandsmake sure there is install jwt package, than check its config file name jwt.php in config folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when I run php artisan jwt:secret it says there are no command defined  in the "jwt" namespace, I have never used that jwt, all my login was with  passport :S